# ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml is missing section 6 'Release'

Tags: tfs

I'm trying to set up Release Management against TFS 2013. Most of the components are installed and configured, and now I'm trying to hook up my proof-of-concept build definition with release manager.

I have installed the ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml template into TFS source control and selected it in the process tab of my build definition... but, contrary to all the guidance/screenshots available on the web, this does not have a section 6, titled 'Release'. What am i doing wrong here?

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMyt8.png)

[Current Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nh4Pb.png)

Comment: You should invest in upgrading to TFS 2017 instead of implementing RM Server 2013. RM Server is deprecated and there is no direct migration path from 2013.

Comment: It is on our plan, but until we migrate to TFS 2017 we are trying to get a simple POC working on TFS13.
So you have a link confirming the lack of migration path? i had read elsewhere that it migrates with the underlying DB.

Comment: I can state with absolute certainty and authority that the RM Server databases are not migrated or converted in any way. Someone from Microsoft should be along to back me up on that shortly. :)

Comment: Thanks - I trust you on that. Still, given we are stuck on TFS2013 for the foreseeable, it'd be great if there was a solution to the template problem I seem to be having. Any ideas?